Instrumentation Amplifier noise on noisy power supply
I have some confusion on the circuit I am looking at. In the case we have a very long cable picking up lots of common mode noise from the atmosphere - it has 4 wires, vsup, V1, V2, and GND and we want to power a measurement circuit to measure the differential voltage (unity only) via the Instrumentation Amp.
In such with lots of noise on ground, how is it possible to deal with this such the circuit ground is no longer noisy? Without removing the noise the CMRR of the in-amp is bypassed as the noise couples to the output via the REF pin.
I have put the ADC in just as an idea of what the circuit would do, but I am primarily interested in just the front-end IN-AMP being able to provide a clean differential output without noise

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Will your cable be shielded? Is there a metal chassis for your electronics?
The differential signal is naturally immune to common-mode interference, since the amplifier performs subtraction.

Hi Vincent, I am primarily interested for an electronics hardware point of view, even if the noise is reduced via shielding etc, how in this case would we stop or remove the remaining noise going onto the 'REF' pin and bouncing the circuit around

From a hardware point of view, common-mode currents must be attenuated by a common-mode choke and diverted to a floating ground or metal chassis. There are always several EMC strategies, but they depend on parameters such as enclosure, environment, cable type, etc. For example, inductive coupling on cables can be mitigated by twisting the wires. But we don't have all this information.

Although it's impossible to answer your question with so little information - and you'll soon understand why I say that - I'll still try to give you some food for thought.
Your cable, unshielded according to your comment, picks up common mode noise. This is what would happen during EN 61000-4-3, -4-4, -4-6 immunity tests. Before stopping or suppressing the residual noise going to the “REF” pin and bouncing the circuit, you need to understand the path of this common-mode noise. In the illustration below you can see that common-mode noise doesn't need a physical link to make a loop. It simply passes through the parasitic capacitances on its way.

Now the question is: Where are the parasitic capacitances in your electronics? And this is precisely where EMC management comes in. Without EMC management, you have no way of knowing. Parasitic return capacitances for common-mode currents depend on your PCB routing and environment. A nearby metal object will create a higher parasitic capacitance, i.e. a lower impedance, for the common-mode current, and this is the return path that will be used.

The solution is not to try to attenuate the noise on the REF pin, but to prevent the noise from entering your electronics. At this point I don't have enough information about your system to give you an answer. If you don't have any metal chassie on your system you can try to attenuate the common mode noise. Bear in mind that a residue of this noise will always enter the system and use the parasitic capacitance with the lowest impedance to return to the external environment.

With a physical or floating grounding system, you can achieve better results by attenuating and then shunting common-mode currents away from your electronic devices.

